# Livetime / uniqueness of NodeId (How to manage NodeIds for dynamic nodes)

Tags: opc-ua, unified-automation-sdk

The Specification (Part 3: Address Space Model) of OPC UA says

> **5.2.2 NodeId**
>
> ... A Server shall persist the NodeId of a Node, that is, it shall not
>   generate new NodeIds when rebooting.

but how can this be?

1. NodeId is a combination from a NamespceIndex and Identifier. NamespceIndex can be changed when the Server is restarting. see:

   > http://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkhp/1.0.0/html/_l2_ua_node_ids.html
   >
   > For this reason, a Client should not persist the namespace index without storing the namespace URI as well, because a namespace URI represented by index “2” during one session could be represented by index “5” during the next session
2. Also the use of FolderType with e.g. "Files" as Items speak again this, or should the server store the NodeId it uses for File-X to assign it right again after restart?
3. What for is "GenericModelChangeEventType" if no NodeId can be created?

**Client:** I thought useing BrowsePath-Path (e.g. "Objects.Server.ServerStatus.CurrentTime" (* ) ) for addressing NodeIds and then using the NodeId while the clinet session to access the nodes is a good approach. Also because Companion Specifications defines the browsename so I might by save. Is this a good idea? ( *need attention on collisions caused by different namespaces)

**Server:** How should the Server behave when it needs to generate/create new NodeIds. Need the NodeIds to be unambiguous all the time or just for the Server runtime. I know some Servers are using NodeIds with String-Typed Identifiers and this String-Identifiers are made from the BrowsePath e.g. "ns=1;s=Server.ServerStatus.CurrentTime". But I don't like this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the OPC UA spec means when it says " A Server shall persist the NodeId of a Node, that is, it shall not generate new NodeIds when rebooting." is as follows: The NodeIds, when seen as a combination of **namespace URI** and identifier, must not change. The server may or may not reassign namespace indices after reboot - but the resulting namespaceURI/Identifier must not change. So, if on the first run I had a node with Identifier 1234 and namespace index 7, and that namespace index corresponded to "http://mynamespace.mycompany.com" in the namespace table, on the second run the same node may have Identifier 1234, but the namespace index 8, as long as in the new NamespaceTable index 8 now corresponds to "http://mynamespace.mycompany.com".

Comment: I think your interpretation is more reasonable. If that's the actual intent then I think the spec should be updated to be more clear on the matter.

Answer (score 3):

1. I think the Unified Automation SDK technically violates the spec in this regard. The recommendation it suggests is good practice for client implementations either way, but as you pointed out, shouldn't strictly be necessary.
2. > Also the use of FolderType with e.g. "Files" as Items speak again this, or should the server store the NodeId it uses for File-X to assign it right again after restart?

I'm not sure what you're asking here.

3. > What for is "GenericModelChangeEventType" if no NodeId can be created?

That's not what is being said here. Nodes can be created and deleted and the structure of objects and variables can change. All the spec is saying is that given Node "Foo" with NodeId "ns=1;s=Foo" it should have the same NodeId if the server reboots.

> I thought useing BrowsePath-Path (e.g. "Objects.Server.ServerStatus.CurrentTime" (* ) ) for addressing NodeIds and then using the NodeId while the clinet session to access the nodes is a good approach.

Browse paths are for programming against types. The approach suggested by the Unified Automation SDK docs is the safe one for persisting NodeIds in your client.

> How should the Server behave when it needs to generate/create new NodeIds. Need the NodeIds to be unambiguous all the time or just for the Server runtime. I know some Servers are using NodeIds with String-Typed Identifiers and this String-Identifiers are made from the BrowsePath e.g. "ns=1;s=Server.ServerStatus.CurrentTime". But I don't like this...

Create them however you like in the Namespaces you control, it's up to you. Using string-based NodeIds allows you to easily "derive" the NodeId from certain other sources, though, e.g. from the address of a variable in a PLC or something similar.